# Extract X Y data from Mapinfo layer data files?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, mapinfo, xy, tab

I have been provided with layer data files from MapInfo (.TAB, .DAT, .ID, .IND, .MAP). These seem to consist of polygons of various sites, but was told they include centre points of each site. I would like to extract any useful data from this including X Y coordinates into a form I can use ideally text. I do not have MapInfo. I have QGIS. Is there a tool or anything I could use to do this please? I am pretty new to the GIS world so please be gentle!

Comment: @Joseph, please write it as an answer

Comment: Hi @Joseph - thank! that worked a treat. Perfect :-) Pleas write as answer and I will vote for it.

Comment: @MarkChidlow - Most welcome, glad it worked =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Polygon centroids** tool from the *Processing Toolbox* and save it as a temporary file.

Then right-click the output temporary file and use the `Save As...` option to save to another format such as csv.